# Desktop icons are not visible when connecting 2nd monitor in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I recently fully installed ubuntu 18.04 on msi gs65 stealth 8sg, which has an nvidia rtx 2080 max-q design. I have connected a 2nd monitor via hdmi and it's working. However, as soon as I connect it the desktop icons dissapear.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed.

Built-in display is 15.4 inches and 2nd monitor is 27 inches. Aligning them horizontally or vertically brought the icons back to desktop.